# I need horizontal scroll bar with fixed width and right side checkbox

Tags: html, css

```
I need horizontal scroll bar with fixed width and right side check box.

Currently I truncate the text, but I need horizontal scroll without truncate.
```

Refer my sample page is here:- https://jsfiddle.net/gsk/hxxk53ey/22/

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: set `overflow-x: scroll;` to your container with your desired width

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/hxxk53ey/23/ as Hossein said

Comment: @AB Udhay - I don't want the individual li scrolling, but i need overall horizontal scrolling for the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think This Is What You Want:

```css
.available-box-options {
    width: 500px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    width: 500px;
 }
.options-box {
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
ul.options {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li div {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
    justify-content: space-between; 
}

.selected-option-icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="available-box-options">
    <div class="options-box">
        <ul class="options centralScrollBar" central-scroll-event="availableItemsScroll()" style="overflow-y: auto">
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > runing</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
                    <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
                    <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>          
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li style="height: 30px; display: block;">
            <div style="height:30px">
               <div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>              
               <div class="selected-option-icon"> <input type="checkbox"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry I've removed some unnecessary styles to make it more readable

**EDIT:**
I've Used Flex Box For That Purpose. Check The New Syntax

Comment: Fine, but the checkbox position was not good. All the checkbox should be show the same alignment.